# How to view a big PDF-file on an HTML page by using an iFrame?

Tags: java, html

I want to view a PDF-file on an HTML page by using Base64 and an iFrame.
When I upload a PDF-file with less than 1kb it works, anything above that number does not.
Test view by object data doesn’t work either.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Concern to big pdf file size:

```
1. On Server site:
   Reduce the file size by using any compression method with output is stream string. (Be better to cache the compressed file).

2. On Client site:
   Uncompress the compressed string (ie. using pako js) to pdf format and display it in the iframe.
```

Enjoy Buddy!

Comment: But my problem not in upload I think not need riduce file because I tried downloading file between display the process complete. but the problem in set  base 64 in ifram src =....

Comment: You means it needs to be decoded into regular pdf format?

Comment: Mention to big pdf size you can also use any slide show inside the iframe, so the file could be split into several string stream over several client request.